# Application taskbar icon set wrong when in a specific path - where is this set?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, icons, taskbar

I'm working on an application (C#/WPF) and when it is installed in the Program Files folder and run the icon on the taskbar shows up wrongly as this;

[image]

But if I rename or copy into another folder the correct icon appears when run. It seems like an icon is set for this file in this path. I've had a look through the registry but with no luck and also cleared the icon cache.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

That is a symptom of the icon being cached and the cache not being refreshed. Normally a restart fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and fixed it through the setup project.

In Visual Studio:

1. right click the setup project.
2. Select View -> File System.
3. Display properties for the shortcut for your application (typically
   under Users Program Menu).
4. The Shortcut will have a property call Icon. Set that to the EXE of your application, or set it to an icon in your setup package.
5. Build the setup project, and then re-install.